# How to cast object of type 'System.Net.FileWebRequest' to type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest'

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm getting the above error above i mention as i have just convert the vb code to csharp. May i know if there is someone who knows how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance

```
 HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = null;
    HttpWebResponse myWebResponse = null;
       string strNo = null;
    strNo = TextBox1.Text;
    try {
        string sURL = "http://gateway.onewaysms.sg:10002/api.aspx";
        sURL = sURL + "?apiusername=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("API3YS3NVIWNP");
        sURL = sURL + "&apipassword=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("API3YS3NVIWNPGNZIV");
        sURL = sURL + "&mobileno=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strNo);
        sURL = sURL + "&senderid=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("onewaysms");
        sURL = sURL + "&languagetype=" + "1";
        sURL = sURL + "&message=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("testing");


      //Error at WebRequest   

        myWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(sURL);
        myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in documentation for [WebRequest.Create()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc.aspx), this method returns descendant of the WebRequest class, depending on Uri schema specified in method parameter. For "http://" schema it returns instance of [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), so you must cast value to appripriate type. To perform a [cast in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx), specify the type that you are casting to in parentheses in front of the value to be converted as shown below. Similarly you must cast result of myWebRequest.GetResponse() to [HttpWebResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
    string strNo = TextBox1.Text;
    try
    {
        string sURL = "http://gateway.onewaysms.sg:10002/api.aspx";
        sURL = sURL + "?apiusername=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("API3YS3NVIWNP");
        sURL = sURL + "&apipassword=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("API3YS3NVIWNPGNZIV");
        sURL = sURL + "&mobileno=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strNo);
        sURL = sURL + "&senderid=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("onewaysms");
        sURL = sURL + "&languagetype=" + "1";
        sURL = sURL + "&message=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("testing");

        HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(sURL);
        HttpWebResponse myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();
        .......
    }
```